# Setting Layout Margins Programmatically not updating layout Android

Tags: android, layout, view, margins

So I have piece together code to adjust the margins of a view programmatically to move a canvas so that the dimensions match the background image. But after changing the margin the view the canvas is associated with does not relocate.

in MyView:

```
if (getLayoutParams() instanceof ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams){ 
    ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams params = (ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams) getLayoutParams();
    params.setMargins(translateX, translateY, 0, 0);
    setLayoutParams(params);
    parentViewGroup.requestApplyInsets();
    parentViewGroup.requestLayout();
    requestLayout();
}
```

Not sure what else to try.

Comment: to what do you set the layout params? is this a custom view?

Comment: yes, just extends View, this is being called in the onSizeChanged override. Also the code is being called, aka layoutParams are instanceof

Comment: what's the value of translateX and translateY you getting? Put a log over there and check

Comment: translateX is 99. Also the view is being created within a fragment if that makes a difference.

Comment: is that the only value you getting or series of values??

Comment: Yes the left margin is the only value I am trying to set at the moment. TranslateY is 0. I believe the layout this view is in is a relative layout, if that helps.

Comment: I think you´ll have to do it outside the View class, on that place where you are using the view.....

Comment: Moved the functionality to the onCreateView() method of the containing fragment, but still doesn't update the left margin of the view. The parameter shows changed, but hasn't moved.

Comment: Nevermind I had to change it to a FrameLayout.LayoutParams. That did it, it is finally working now, thankyou.